# Does "the flip side" refer only to the negative aspects of something?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I understand that the expression "[the flip side](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flip+side)" is generally used to refer to the "negative" aspect of someone or something.

I think the expression comes from the meaning of the 
*"flip side (of a gramophone record) from  1949.*"  (etymological online dictionary)

Why is  "flip side" often used to suggest a negative connotation? Can it be used to convey a positive aspect?

Comment: its from 'on the other hand' because transferring an object from one hand to the other flips it. i personally don't see it as negative

Comment: @Jon Mark Perry, this makes transferring a cup of coffee from one hand to the other particularly painful.

Comment: @Silenus; well if you're clever you flip it across the vertical axis

Comment: I thought it might come from the concept that a coin has two sides.

Comment: Theoretically it could refer to something psoitive, if it's the flip side of something negative. However, often a more explicitly positive expression is used, like "the upside of X".

Comment: It is used to imply that the two aspects are inseparable. You must take the one with the other, no cherry picking and no workarounds. It's as much about entailment as dichotomy. "The job offer is attractive, but the flipside is having to relocate to Atlanta." So at the very least, it can be used when you don't know whether the flip side will be good or bad.

Comment: It is not necessarily negative.  It's just treated as secondary or less important.

Answer (score 1):

**The flip side** means — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flip+side)

> *(Music, other)* another term for B-side

Now **B-side** means — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/B-side)

> *n (Music, other)* the less important side of a gramophone record. Also called: flip side.

It is the less important side because it has the relatively bad songs. That's the main idea.

However, "the flip side" can also simply mean "on the other hand". The good and bad sides are inseparable, as in the two sides of a coin. If you first talk about the negatives, then "the flip side" will be the positives. It is rarely used this way, though.

> a different aspect of something (especially the opposite aspect)

Note: You can say "the flip side" even when in doubt which aspect of something is good or bad. It's better to use "the bright side", "the upside", etc. to make sure you're referring to a positive aspect of something.

Comment: So it can be used to express both a negative and a positive aspect? It just depends on context?

Comment: @Saturana More often used to imply the negative side. But also, yeah.

Comment: I don't know of any examples offhand, but I've heard that there were a number of cases where the song on the "flip side" of a record wound up being more popular than the A-side song.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, nobody can predict well what song will be the next hit. :)